# Space opera book series – not on Earth, rival humanoid enemy

Tags: story-identification

I read the first book of the series in the last 5 years (2015-2020) – seemed quite 'new', possibly on Kindle/Goodreads/another kindle friendly platform. I do not have access to that Kindle account anymore.

Following humans but don't think it was set on Earth. Follows a group of young adults trying to make it into an academy or space cadet system.

They end up in teams of 4 per ship.

One had taken his brothers identity I think and was a low level courier doing illegal jobs between cities. One was the daughter of one of the highest ranked female officers – but only just scraped through. One was from a farm planet and the last was an infiltrator from the species they were trying to attack.

One of the instructors had been previously injured in a battle and was part of the intelligence unit – who was getting close romantically(?) to the infiltrator – who could swim? longer than normal cadets due to her physiology – even though she looked the same.

Spoiler:

> The aliens they were fighting against thought that they were attacked first, whilst the people that we're following are told that the aliens attacked first. Some kind of government/military conspiracy.

Comment: Hi Matt and welcome to the SFF SE :-) To help trigger my (failing) memory any details you can remember would be useful e.g. names of people, or places, or spaceships, planets or indeed anything like that. Is there anything of this type you can add to your question?

Comment: Thanks for having me! Unfortunately I cannot remember any of the names of factions or characters for certain - I've read a lot of this genre and seem to be getting them mixed up. I've searches a lot for one of the main male characters being called 'Zach' or 'Zak' but I think I'm getting confused with many of the other posts I've read. I do however remember that during cadet training there were 4 'slots' per team, Captain, navigator, weapons but I can't remember the last one. Obviously everyone wanted to be captain - but the officers daughter failed and disappointed her mother.

Comment: It reminds me a bit of ender's game, so perhaps it is worth it to look up similar books to that one.

Comment: Thank you - I've not read that book so it will be a welcome distraction whilst I'm looking!